# If I rotate a system by $2\pi$, will I invert it?

Tags: quantum-spin, fermions, rotation

In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/298689/179151), I saw the following

> ...if you have a two-fermion system, interchanging them is equivalent to rotating the system by an angle $2\pi$.

But in my view, rotating the system by $2\pi$ does not interchange the particles, but rather results in the same system. By interchange here, I mean $(p_1,p_2)\to(p_2,p_1)$.

Why rotating a system by 2π the same as reversing the particles?

Comment: First notice that because the wavefunction of two fermions is antisymmetric, the "inversion of states" you mention results in a phase of $(-1)$ if the pair is in the spin triplet state and a phase of $(+1)$ if the pair is in the spin singlet state.

Comment: I know, but the question wasn't that.

Comment: If you interchange two particles, you rotate each by $\pi$. This is equivalent to fixing one and rotating the other $2\pi$ around the fixed one. So, the interchange is equivalent to a $2\pi$ rotation (the origin of rotation being the position of one of the two particles). See [this figure](https://media.springernature.com/lw685/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41567-020-1019-1/MediaObjects/41567_2020_1019_Fig1_HTML.png). This is really all I meant.

Comment: Good answered my question, I will try to understand here, but thank you

Comment: I Got  to understand, you Help a lot with my doubt

Answer (score 6):

The operator for rotating a field with spin $\sigma$ through an angle $\theta$ has the form
$ e^{i\sigma\theta}$, so a “complete” rotation of $\theta=2\pi$ radians will cause a spin-half particle to accumulate a phase factor of $e^{i\frac12 2\pi} = -1$.

Warning, warning: the previous sentence is oversimplified enough that anyone who’s worked through the details will have complaints about it — me included. As I remember, the “simple” treatment in [Streater and Wightman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691070628) is ten or fifteen pages long. But the gist of my oversimplification is correct: spinors “double cover” the rotation group, and must rotate through $2\times2\pi$ radians to return to their initial state.

The double-cover property of spinor rotations is closely related to the spin-statistics theorem, which says a state with two identical particles of spin $\sigma$ must accumulate a phase $(-1)^{2\sigma}$ when the particles are exchanged: that is, two-boson wavefunctions are symmetric under exchange, and two-fermion wavefunctions are antisymmetric.

In the early decades of quantum field theory it was believed this sign change under “complete” rotations was a mathematical curiosity, because the absolute phase of a single fermion isn’t an observable. However, interferometry permits observation of phase differences, and the phase change of single neutrons under a $2\pi$ rotation was first observed [in 1975](https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(75)90798-7).

Your [linked answer (v2)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/298689/44126) seems to be saying

1. Rotating a spinor field by $2\pi$ introduces a phase factor of $-1$.
2. Exchanging two identical fermions introduces a phase change of $-1$.
3. Therefore, rotating a two-fermion state by $2\pi$ has the same effect as exchanging the particles.

This is different from how I understand the relationship among these effects. I am under the impression that you accumulate the rotation-phase for each particle in the state. So rotating your two-fermion system about its center by a half-turn, $\frac{2\pi}{2}$ radians, would give a phase factor $e^{i\pi/2} = i$ on each particle, or a total phase $-1$ for the system, at the same time as putting particle $A$ in the position of particle $B$ and vice-versa.

That is to say, I think you’re right: a *half*-turn is the same as an exchange for a two-fermion system. If the linked answer is actually correct, that’s very interesting.

Comment: I wanted to understand exactly why particles switch in rotation, why does this happen?

Comment: Apparently they didn't understand the question since they gave you likes too

Comment: He says this before showing that the result is equivalent, as if before knowing that the result was negative he says that rotating 2π gives us the inversion of the particles

Comment: @Ian It's hard for me to understand precisely what you're saying in these comments.  Who are you referring to as "he"?  Can you rephrase your last comment?

Comment: He's the guy who posted the post I said above

Answer (score 1):

Yes, classically turning around by $2\pi$ is the trivial transformation. However the whole new thing about spinors is that for them this transformation is not trivial - the spinor instead changes sign. But because all provabilities involve spinor bilinears they don't change and this allows such novel objects in the quantum theory.

Comment: That's not the Question, I had a picture more edited and took, what I mean is that in a post here was said that the states reverse, not the signal, reverse the coordinates, (p1, p2) turn (p2, p1)

Comment: When I said reverse the image I put showed that it was the moments of the system that reversed as in the symmetry of the wave function in quantum mechanics not relativistic

Comment: The lack of clarity for you to deduce that was this is because they took the image when editing what takes away the context

Comment: Rotating one fermion around itself gives a sign of $(-1)$. Shouldn't rotating two fermions around themselves gove a sign of $(-1)^2$?

Comment: I don't understand what you said., What's got to do with it?

Comment: @lan ok, I'll address your question somewhat later

Comment: Thank you, I hope you can

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion, we do not rotate a physical system at some angle; instead, we recalculate the observational results from one still reference system to another one turned at this angle with respect to the original reference frame. So, observation of a QM system at the angle $0+\varepsilon$ may not be different from observation at the angle $2\pi - \varepsilon$, if $\varepsilon\to 0$.

The difference between spin and a classical angular momentum  is in quantizing the spin projections $S_z$ and in discretenes of the total spin $S$. Any observation implies exchange of the energy with the system, so the system never stays the same if observed - we observe **transitions**. In Classical Mechanics, where the space is 3D and the maximum "rotation" angle is $2\pi$, there is another implicit hypothesis, namely, our observation does not change the system, contrary to QM. If you forget observation influence, then you reason in terms of non observable constructs and you have paradoxes everywhere.

Interchange of **identical particles** (their mutual transitions) may not lead to any physical effect by definition of identical particles; thus the wave function is (anty) symmetric and may only acquire an inessential sign factor (whatever it is) disappearing from observable quantities.

Comment: The sign obtained from exchanging identical particles isn't inessential and does have physical effects, since precisely this sign distinguishes fermions from bosons.

Comment: @Andrew: Right, but I am speaking of "rotations" of two fermions.